# Fortran OpenMP Open Function In Parallel Region

Tags: fortran, openmp

I am trying to open and read different files(same structure) in each thread in parallel. Essentially, I have different unit number for each file given by tnm variable so that I don't open and close the same file being used in another thread. The  code below runs for a while and reports that file does not exist(See the Slurm error message in a link). I am quite lost because file exists and this behavior is not consistent. For example, in a different run, this error will show up when reading a different file(also existing). Does anyone know what the problem is? Is this a bug?

I am using slurm, and ifort for a compiler
compiling flags are -r8 -O2 -trace -qopenmp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3tFm.jpg)

```
subroutine ReadPlane()
real :: tt, rhoinf, uinf, twall, xLt, yLt, zlt
integer :: kplane, nn, imaxo, jmaxo, klo
integer :: i,j,tnm,ierror
character(200) :: fname
character(3) :: fnext
character(8) :: fnum
!$omp parallel do num_threads(32) &
!$omp private(fnum,fnext,fname) &
!$omp private(i,j) &
!$omp private(imaxo,jmaxo,klo,rhoinf,uinf,tinf,twall,tnm,ierror)&
!$omp private(u,v,w,p,t,rho)
do kplane=1,kend
  allocate(u(imax,jmax),v(imax,jmax),w(imax,jmax))
  allocate(p(imax,jmax),t(imax,jmax),rho(imax,jmax))
  tnm = kplane+100
  write(unit=fnext,fmt='(i3)')100+kplane
  write(unit=fnum,fmt=fmtstr)n
  fname = trim(datadir)//trim(fnum)//'H/REST/old_plane.'//fnext
  if(kplane.eq.1)print*,'Reading Volume '//trim(fnum)//'H'
  open(tnm,file=fname,form='unformatted',status='old',iostat=ierror)
  if (ierror .ne. 0) print*, 'error!',tnm,fname
  rewind tnm
  read(tnm) tt,nn,imaxo,jmaxo,klo
  read(tnm) rhoinf,uinf,tinf,twall
  read(tnm) xLt,yLt,zlt
  read(tnm) ((u(i,j),i=1,imaxo),j=1,jmaxo),&
           ((v(i,j),i=1,imaxo),j=1,jmaxo),&
           ((w(i,j),i=1,imaxo),j=1,jmaxo),&
           ((p(i,j),i=1,imaxo),j=1,jmaxo),&
           ((t(i,j),i=1,imaxo),j=1,jmaxo),&
           ((rho(i,j),i=1,imaxo),j=1,jmaxo)
  close(tnm)
  u2(kplane,1:imax2,1:jmax) = u(istart:iend,1:jmax)
  v2(kplane,1:imax2,1:jmax) = v(istart:iend,1:jmax)
  w2(kplane,1:imax2,1:jmax) = w(istart:iend,1:jmax)
  p2(kplane,1:imax2,1:jmax) = p(istart:iend,1:jmax)
  t2(kplane,1:imax2,1:jmax) = t(istart:iend,1:jmax)
  r2(kplane,1:imax2,1:jmax) = rho(istart:iend,1:jmax)
  deallocate(u,v,w,p,t,rho)
end do
!$omp end parallel do

return
end subroutine ReadPlane
```

Edit :  I added a secondary open statement inside of the "if (ierror .ne. 0) print*, 'error!',tnm,fname" to attempt to open the file again and it works fine with this work around. This is such a weird behavior where it randomly fails to open an existing file. Does anyone know why the code fails to load randomly the first time?

```
  if (ierror .ne. 0) then 
    print*, 'error!',tnm,fname
    ierror = 0 
 open(tnm,file=fname,form='unformatted',status='old',iostat=ierror)
    if (ierror .ne. 0) print*, 'error again!',tnm,fname
  endif
```

Comment: fyi kplane ranges from 1 to 120

Comment: Is your treatment of `fnext` correct? I thought a unit is a number, but you have it as a `character(3)`. Also, I don't see an `open` statement that associates the unit with a file.

Comment: yes, the use of fnext is correct. file name is prepared in fname statement. unit fnext and unit fnum are just there to automate the file naming. It just takes the value assigned from the write statement into fnext and fnum. For example, fnext will take in a value of 100+kplane and num will take in a value of n. Both are fed into fname which is the name of the file I read.  If you look at the open statement, you can see that it is reading fname file.

Comment: unit doesn't necessarily have to be a number I don't think. But regardless, it fnext has nothing to do with the unit number used for open statement. open takes in an integer tnm as a unit number.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Actually, I added a secondary open statement inside of the 
"if (ierror .ne. 0) print*, 'error!',tnm,fname" to attempt to open the file again and it works fine with this work around. This is such a weird behavior where it randomly fails to open an existing file.

Comment: Have you posted your complete code? I only see a subroutine. I have no idea what is in that image because you shuold not post images here. Everything in a code block.

Comment: Code is thousands of lines of code that does something irrelevant to the question. I can't share the entire code anyways due to non-disclosure clause. This is a subroutine that reads some profile. All the OPENMP calls as well as variables relevant to open function should be all in here.

Comment: Please add a print statement that reads prints the file name before opening it. Show what it prints befire it fails. Try to create a [mcve] and show the complete output - we understand that it may be specific to your SLURM environment, but too much is hidden at present.

Comment: Please make a minimal example. Since you are hiding code from us, I'll guess that the error is in the code we don't see. I've made a minimal example that shows that what you want is perfectly fine. Unfortunately I can not post multi-line code in this comment.